# Mage::getModel() - getCollection() on non-object on staging server

Tags: php, magento, module

I've created a custom banner module for Magento and I've tested it locally on my Vagrant/VirtualBox setup running an instance of precise32 and everything is working great.

When I pulled the code from GitHub on to a staging server the extension is not working and I'm getting the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /var/colourbox/app/code/local/AffinityCloud/ACBanners/Block/Slider.php on line 7, referer: http://colourbox.affinitycloud.co.uk/tub-storage.html

This is while viewing the home page, so I'm not sure why it's referencing http://colourbox.affinitycloud.co.uk/tub-storage.html as the referer as this is a category page.

I've cleared the cache (is disabled anyway) and reindexed. Stil no joy. I've also tried to rename the model classes using lowercase characters and the first character uppercase with no result.

I've added the module code to GitHub below so you can see the code:

https://github.com/garethdaine/acbanners

Any ideas why this would be working locally and not on the staging server? It's as if it can't find the model classes but has no problem fining the Slider.php class.

I'm at a loss as to what to do here.

**NOTE**: For brevity, I would like to add that I have logged out and back in to the admin, while also deleting the module tables and the reference in core_resource to no avail. It creates the tables fine but I still get the same issues and the module is showing as enabled in the advanced config.

Comment: Can you post the `config.xml` file of your module and the line that gives you the error?

Comment: Aaa...never mind... It seams I can't read...I can get the module from github.

Comment: Hey, all the code is at the GitHub URL in the question https://github.com/affinitycloud/acbanners. The line that gives me the error is $bannersCollection = Mage::getModel('acbanners/acbanners')->getCollection(); line 7 in Slider.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is case sensitivity.
On windows systems the file names are not case sensitive. On Unix they are case sensitive.

So in the ways you configured the module and named the files, when calling `Mage::getModel('acbanners/acbanners')` the magento autoloader looks for the file

`AffinityCloud/ACBanners/Model/Acbanners.php`  But the real name of your file  is   `AffinityCloud/ACBanners/Model/ACBanners.php`

So the file is not found and the class is not loaded and `Mage::getModel(...)` returns null.

You have 2 options here.

1. The cleanest and fastest. rename all your classes in the `Model` folder to start with a capital letter and the rest should be lowercase. `Acbanners.php` in the example above. You may need to do the same for the files in `Block` and `Helper`.
2. The long version. If you want to keep the file names you need to change `Mage::getModel('acbanners/acbanners')` to `Mage::getModel('acbanners/aCBanners')` or `Mage::getModel('acbanners/ACBanners')`. but I guess this will take a lot of refactoring. You may also need this for blocks and helpers also.

Comment: I thought it may be case sensitivity. I'm not developing on a Windows machine though, I'm developing on my Mac using Vagrant/VirtualBox, which is a copy of the staging server. So should this really be happening. Also, how come it can find the other classes but not the Model classes.

Comment: Oh yeah...it's the same for Mac. Try renaming the class I suggested and see if the error disappears or changes.

Comment: Thanks dude. OK, that has fixed the frontend error but the admin still goes to a 404 when trying to manage the banners.

Comment: @Gaz. I guess you have to rename the controller file also. from `Adminhtml/ACBannersController.php` to `Adminhtml/AcbannersController.php`

Comment: Marius is right, Me too have faced such errors, only keeping First letter Capital keeps issues away.

Comment: OK, thanks folks. I've renamed all folders, files and references to them to lowercase with the first letter capital and everything works great now. Thanks again.